# No puedo mostrar videos en mi Pagina

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Estoy usando la api de youtube para mostrar los video subidos del canal, pero pide autorización siempre.

Este es el codigo que estoy usando.

[YOUTUBE  DATA API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/javascript)

Pero me gustaría que no pidiera autorización para poder ver lo videos, alguien que me pueda ayudar a encontrar una solución, gracias.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La verdad no encuentro nada relacionado a esto en la documentación de la API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes profundizar en esta entrada https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48052738/youtube-api-channels-videos-list, pero básicamente sería hacer algo así:

```
  $.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search",{
      part : 'snippet', 
      channelId : 'CHANNEL_ID', // You can get one from Advanced settings on YouTube
      type : 'video',
      key: 'YOUR_KEY'},
      function(data) {
        $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
          $('#results').append('<li>https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + item.id.videoId + '</li>');
        })
      }
  )
})
```

Según dice el post, "debes usar https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search endpoint en lugar de https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels. Proporciona un channelId y parámetros de tipo (el parámetro de tipo puede ser video, playlist, channel)".

Comment: Hola buen dia, ya mismo lo voy a ensayar y te cuento gracias!!

Comment: Si señor un duro para esto !!!! GRACIAS!!!!